# How to display only one transcript per gene on ggbio?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, genome

On R, using the ggbio package : how to display a genetrack with only one transcript per gene and with transcripts annotated with their gene symbol.
Transcripts can be displayed on multiples lines (overlap between transcripts is okay).
I tried the following code :

```
genetrack <-autoplot(Homo.sapiens, GRanges(paste0("chr",chr), IRanges(genestart - bpwindow, genestop + bpwindow)))
```

Including using the option stat = "reduce" but the result wasn't what I wanted (gene condensed on one track without overlap and labels too close to be readable).
Tried filtering the Homo.sapiens object from library(Homo.sapiens) but I failed.